# In django i want to change the date from views

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I want to update the date from the backend views in django how can i did that here are my views where i want to do this
explaining what i exactly want to achive i am building a crm where clients suppose to pay monthly or quaterly depends on their plan i have given a button at dashbord which triggers this function and redirect to homepage in this function if the user date month came then this function is suppose to generate the bills which is fetching in the homepage and show outstanding amount what wrong happen with this idea everytime pressing the button it will genertate duplicate bills adding in revenue to stops this i add a variable is eligible which i thought the user will change it manually but then i feel it is more good to update the date

```
def refresh_dashboard(request):
    date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime ("%Y%m%d")
    m = datetime.date.today()
    print(f"the date is {m}")
    customer = Customer.objects.all()
    for i in customer:
        # print(i.eligible)
        period = i.next_payment.strftime("%Y%m%d")
        
        if period <= date and i.eligible == True:
            x = Bill.objects.create(name = i.name,status ="unpaid",price = i.recuring_amount,generate_date = date)
            x.save()
            obj = i
            # obj.next_payment.strftime("%Y%(m+1)%d")
            obj.eligible = False
            obj.save()
            # print(f"the date is {date} and the obtain from the customer is {period}")
            # print(f"this customer  {i.name} bill need to be generated")
    # print(f"the date is {datetime.datetime.now()}")
    return redirect('/')
```

Comment: Be more precise... Update how. Periodically, on a user action or other way ???

Comment: i have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increment `datetime` on the basis of given days using `timedelta`

```
    from datetime import datetime  
    from datetime import timedelta #new

    today = datetime.now() 
    print(f"Today's the date & Time is {today}")
    month_later = today+ timedelta(days=MONTHLY_CYCLE)
    three_months_later = today+ timedelta(days=QUA_CYCLE)
    six_months_later = today+ timedelta(days=SIX_MONTH_CYCLE)
    print(f"three_months_later's the date & Time is {month_later}")
    print(f"three_months_later's the date & Time is {three_months_later}")
    print(f"six_months_later's the date & Time is {six_months_later}")
    
    customer = Customer.objects.get(pk=id) # Targeted Customer 
    selected_cycle = int(customer.billing_cycle) #return the value of billing_cycle selected from Customer
    tentative_date = today+ timedelta(days=selected_cycle) 
    print(f"tentative_date Billing date & Time is {month_later}") # Required DAte.
```

This is how you can update the `datetime`. rest you can implement as required.